# BiGrams Spark using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata, n-gram

I already have the sentences in a RDD and the output looks like:

> RT @DougJ7777: If Britain wins #Eurovision then we have to rejoin the
> EU. It's in the rules. #Eurovision2018 RT @Mystificus: Of course I'll
> watch #eurovision tonight. After all, 200 million people can't be
> wrong, can they? Er...... RT @KlNGNEUER: Me when Europeans make
> fun of Eurovision VS Me when Americans make fun of Eurovision
>
> #Eurovision #EuroSemi2 Eurovision song contest 2018 tonight!!!!!! Saturday chills with bae, hands up who’s not watching
> Eurovision… @AndrewDawes71 @SuzanneEvans1
> @ConstantinStHe1 The tweet was directed at citizens of other countries
> partaking in t…  Looking forward to @Eurovision
> @bbceurovision tonight and rooting for @surieofficial who has strong
> competition. Sh…  RT @Jem_Collins: Media and
> journalism friends, I need you to do something during #Eurovision this
> evening. And that something is to drink a… Getting ready for anime AND
> Eurovision with friends tonight!

But when I try to split it by "." and "," I only get a empty txt using this code:

```
JavaRDD<String> sentences= lines.flatMap( line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(".")).iterator());
JavaRDD<String> words = sentences.flatMap( line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator());
```

Where lines is an RDD with the content of the screenshot.

After that, how can I construct the bigrams?

REPRODUCE EXAMPLE:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("BiGramsApp");
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> inputFile = sparkContext.textFile(input);
JavaRDD<String> sentences = inputFile.flatMap(  line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(".")).iterator());
JavaRDD<String> words = sentences.flatMap( line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator());
    
words.saveAsTextFile(outputDir);
```

The input file will be a .txt with any sentence, but you can try with the strings that are write at the beginning

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also `String.split()` takes a regular expression and `.` has a special meaning in regex that you probably didn't intend to invoke.

Comment: But I don't get it, why in this case is not working.... Because it works in a normal string

Comment: `string.split(".")` will always produce that kind of effect. Can you provide an [mre]? I'm pretty sure your issue has nothing to do with spark and it should be re-producible in 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: I think that this example should work

Comment: You missed the "r" in "mre". Neihter `input` nor `outputDir` are defined anywhere. I was thinking more along the lines of `String x = "... something ..."; List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(x.split(".")); System.out.println(strings)`. Do that with some selected input sentence from your input to verify that it's not just Spark doing some magic weirdness. What you're seeing is the perfectly normal behaviour of `String.split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to split is add the pattern between `"[.]"` or `"[ ]"`